# Lipschitz and Absolute Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-measure

A problem in Royden & Fitzpatrick:

Define $f$ and $g$ on $[-1,1]$ by

$f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and

$g(x)=x^2cos(\frac{\pi}{2x})$ if $x\neq0$, $x\in[-1,1]$

$g(x)=0$, if $x=0$.

$(i)$ Show that both $f$ and $g$ are absolutely continuous on $[-1,1]$

$(ii)$ For the partition $P_n=<-1,0,\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}...,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},1>$ Examine $V(f(g),P_n)$

$(iii)$ Show that $f(g)$ fails to be of bounded variation, and hence also fails to be absolutely continuous on $[-1,1]$

MY ATTEMPT: (EDIT)

$(i)$ $f'(x)$ is bounded $=>f$ is Lipschitz $=>f$ is absolutely continuous. I show the derivatives of both functions are bounded and I'm done. (WRONG - just realized. Is there any way other than directly showing absolute continuity, I have trouble with doing so rigorously)

$(ii)$ I am computing this bruteforce, if you have a better suggestion please let me hear it before I die of boredom.

$(iii)$ Since I made a mistake in $(i)$, I'm guessing this will be an easy consequence of $(ii)$ if I can show the variation for each $n$ is a series that diverges.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you are familiar with this characterization of absolutely continuous function: $f$ is absolutely continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ the derivative $f'$ of $f$ exists almost everywhere, is in $L^1$, and 
$$
f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(s)ds
$$
for some $a$.

---

1. Using the characterization I just mentioned, note
   $$
   f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}
   $$
   and 
   $$
   g'(x)=2x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2x}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2x}\right)
   $$
   Both are well defined, except on $0$, are Lebesgue integrable, and belong to $L^1([-1,1])$.
2. (I think you are looking for a somewhat short and elegant way of making the calculation here, right? I don't know if the argument to do the calculation I will show can be considered elegant, but I don't think this can be done any better). Note $g(-1)=2cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$, $g(0)=0$ and 
   $$
   g\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{1}{k^2}\cos(\frac{k\pi}{2})=
   \begin{cases}
   0 & k \text{ odd}\\
   -\frac{1}{k^2} & k = 2j, j \text{ odd}\\
   \frac{1}{k^2} & k = 2j, j \text{ even}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   which implies 
   $$
   f\circ g\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)=
   \begin{cases}
   f(0)=0 & k \text{ odd}\\
   -\frac{1}{k^{2/3}} & k=2j, j \text{ odd}\\
   \frac{1}{k^{2/3}} & k=2j, j \text{ even}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   Then, we deduce, for k even,
   $$
   \left\vert f \circ g\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)-f \circ g\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right\vert = \frac{1}{k^{2/3}}
   $$
   and for k odd, 
   $$
   \left\vert f \circ g\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)-f \circ g\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right\vert = \frac{1}{(k+1)^{2/3}}
   $$
   With all this, we deduce 
   $$
   V(f(g),P_n)=2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{2/3}}
   $$
   What can you say about this series?

---

Edit for part 1: Since you are assumed to not know the characterization I just mentioned for absolute continuity, here I will show other ways of proving absolute continuity of $g$ and $f$
 .

Notice $\vert g'(x)\vert\leq 2+\pi$ for all $x\in[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$. This implies $g$ is Lipschitz.

For $f$, we will prove it by definition. Let $\epsilon>0$. We want to show there is $\delta>0$
s.t. if $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i},y_{i})$ (with $x_{i}<y_{i}$) is s.t. $m(S)<\delta$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vert f(y_{i})-f(x_{i})\vert<\epsilon$.

When $0 \notin (x_i,y_i)$, we have $f$ is derivable, hence by the  fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(y_i)-f(x_i)=\int_{x_i}^{y_i}f'(s)ds$. When $0 \in (x_i,y_i)$, we note, for $a_n\searrow 0$, 
$$
h_{a_n}(x):=f'(x)1_{[a_n,y_i]}\nearrow h_0(x):=f'(x)1_{(0,y_i]}
$$
pointwise, thus by monotone convergence theorem, 
$$
y_i^{1/3}-a_n^{1/3}=\int h_{a_n}(x)dx\\
=\int_{a_n}^{y_i} f'(x)dx\\
\nearrow \int h_0(x)dx\\
= \int_0^{y_i}f'(x)dx=y_i^{1/3}
$$
thus $\int_0^{y_i}f'(x)dx=(y_i)^{1/3}$ is well defined. Likewise $\int_{x_i}^0 f'(x)dx=-(x_i)^{1/3}$, thus $f(y_i)-f(x_i)=\int_{x_i}^{y_i}f'(s)ds$.

Hence, we can say
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\vert f(y_{i})-f(x_{i})\vert & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\vert\int_{x_{i}}^{y_{i}}\frac{1}{3}s^{-2/3}ds\right\vert\\
& \leq & \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{x_{i}}^{y_{i}}\frac{1}{3}\vert s^{-2/3}\vert ds\\
& = & \int_{S}\frac{1}{3}\vert s^{-2/3}\vert ds
\end{eqnarray}

Let $\delta$ be s.t. $(\delta/2)^{1/3}-(-\delta/2)^{1/3}<\epsilon$ and $S$ s.t. $m(S)<\delta$. We can show 
$$
\int_{S}\frac{1}{3}\vert s^{-2/3}\vert ds\leq \int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2}\frac{1}{3}\vert s^{-2/3}\vert ds=(\delta/2)^{1/3}-(-\delta/2)^{1/3}<\epsilon
$$
(ie, the "worst case" is $S=(-\delta/2,\delta/2)$). This shows $f$ absolutely continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. Part ii) looks much better than my long direct calculations. 

However, for i), the characterization of absolute continuity that you mention is part of the next section, and I assume they do not want me to show this result using later material. 

The main tools I have so far are

 "lipschitz => absolutely continuous",

 "linear combinations of absolutely continuous functions are absolutely continuous" 

and "if f continuous on [a,b] then absolute continuity is equivalent to the sequence of divided differences being uniformly integrable over [a,b]"

Comment: Nice to know you found the proof of ii) I posted useful. Regarding i), I have just edited my post to include proofs that $f$ and $g$ are absolutely continuous, using tools you are familiar with.

Comment: Thanks once again, this is an excellent answer. Transferring from the difference of $|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|$ to the integral in the first equality is very nice. I'll keep that trick in mind!

Comment: For part $(ii)$ I am guessing the only thing left to say about the series representing the variation of $f(g)$ is that the supremum of the variations over all partitions is unbounded. So $f(g)$ is not of bounded variation and therefore the composition of absolutely continuous functions is not necessarily absolutely continuous.

Comment: Glad to know you found my answer useful. On part iii), indeed, that is the right conclusion. On part i), the argument used to prove $f$ is absolutely continuous also gives an idea about why the characterization of absolute continuity I mentioned initially is true, as well.

Comment: Since the problem is mentioned in Royden before the characterization of absolute continuity you mentioned in the first part of your solution, can we solve it by using information until pg.123

Comment: @Secretly Sorry, I have never seen Royden's book, thus I can't answer your question.

Comment: I can send it to you on your email if you like?@NateRiver

Comment: @Secretly No need to. I have downloaded it. Will give it a look, then come back with an answer. However, I am busy at this moment, so it'll take a while before I can answer your question.

Comment: Okay, this is problem #43 in section 6.4 on pg.123 in Royden 4th edition

Comment: which property leads you to write Note
\begin{eqnarray}
\vert f(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i})\vert & = & \left\vert\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}\frac{1}{3}s^{-2/3}ds\right\vert\\
\end{eqnarray} 
 in the fifth line of your edit?

Comment: Ah, good catch. The fundamental theorem of calculus states: $f(b)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f'(s)ds$, but that's only true if $f$ is derivable on $[a,b]$. So this works for all $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ s.t. 0 is not in that interval.  I'll modify the proof in a while for the interval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ s.t. 0 is in that interval.

Comment: Also, your derivative of $g$ lacks 2 in the denominator in the second term and the second term should be positive and your $g(1/k)$ in 2tha angle of the cosine should be integer multiple of $\pi/2$ not $\pi$

Comment: I think this will leads to correction of part 2

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573066/show-that-both-f-and-g-are-absolutely-continuous-on-1-1/1573174#1573174 here it said that this step (the above good catch) is justified by monotone convergence theorem but I do not understand how

Comment: @Mathstupid Nice. Corrected answer taking your comments into account.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'll add to Nate's answer by showing $g'(0)=0$. By definition, $$g'(0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{2x})}{x}$$ Since $-1 \leq \cos (\frac{\pi}{2x}) \leq 1 \implies -x \leq x\cos (\frac{\pi}{2x}) \leq x $ and by squeeze theorem, we are done.

For (1), an easier way is presented in [Proof that $\sqrt x$ is absolutely continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543221/proof-that-sqrt-x-is-absolutely-continuous) but the proof essentially follows through: if $0<t\leq x < y$, then $(y-t)^{1/3}-(x-t)^{1/3} \geq y^{1/3}-x^{1/3}$ since $f'(t)=\frac{1}{3(x-t)^{1/3}}-\frac{1}{3(y-t)^{1/3}}\geq 0$ for $f(t)=(y-t)^{1/3}+(x-t)^{1/3}$ and now, for a given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon^3$ and shift your disjoint intervals, as done in the link.